# Definition of ordering $<$ on $\mathbb R$ and show it satisfy the Trichotomy Law and is compatible with $+$ and $\times$.

Tags: real-analysis

> Definition of ordering $<$ on $\mathbb R$ and show it satisfy the Trichotomy Law and  is compatible with $+$ and $\times$.

I use the ordering $<$ on $\mathbb R$ every day and I take all its properties for granted without even knowing the definition of it.

Usually to determine whether $a < b$, I look at their decimal representations and find the first index at which they differ to determine whether $b$'s digit is greater than $a's$ digit using the ordering $<_N$ on $\mathbb N$.

Been searching on the internet some informal definitions are given: plot the numbers on the real axis and order them left to right. However, I guess this is not the exact definition ?

Where can I look the definition of the ordering $<$ on $\mathbb R$ up ? It must be stated somewhere ? - I mean we use it everyday and it is implemented in computers ?

The following article describe some of the properties of the ordering $<$ on real numbers I use everyday:

http://www.proofwiki.org/wiki/Ordering_Properties_of_Real_Numbers

Answer (score 2):

The answer may depend on how you defined $\mathbb R$ in the first place, but you can use this:
$$ a<b\iff \exists c\ne0\colon b=a+c^2$$

Comment: To repeat, we should *really* know how you defined $\mathbb R$. After all, a defining property may be that every nonempty bounded set has a supremum - this already takes an order for granted.

Comment: I know $\mathbb R$ is defined as a totally ordered field. However, there must be some standard implementation of the real numbers and their ordering ? - I can't find this standard implementation even thus it must exist, like for the natural numbers ??

Answer (score 2):

You can define the ordering on $\mathbb R$ by starting with the notion of a *positive number*.

> **Definition.** Suppose $x$ and $y$ are real numbers. Then $x>y$ if and only if $x-y$ is positive.

I prefer this definition because it allows us to easily deduce many of the properties of the ordering on $\mathbb R$: if you think for a moment it should be clear from the definition, for example, that 
$$
x>y\implies x+c>y+c.
$$

But this definition isn't really used in the "real world": <strike>computers and</strike> people compare the sizes of numbers by looking at their <strike>binary and</strike> decimal expansions, respectively.

**Edit:** Computers apparently *do* compare integers by subtracting them.

Comment: Actually, computers compare two integers by substracting them and see if the result is negative. However, there must be some standard definition of the real numbers and the ordering ?